# Better way to act on grid data?

Tags: info-visualisation, grid, experience

I need to assign different levels of permissions to users in a grid. But in-line/direct editing of grid data is not allowed!

As shown in the mockup below, in the action column, clicking "Add" will give a dropdown in the permissions column and choosing the appropriate permission is one of the possible ways but is not allowed for some reason.

I need to assign permissions to users (shown in the grid).

[image]

Is there any alternative I can use to assign permissions to users in the grid?

Comment: it will help if you can if you can explain your image a bit more (or at least elaborate more on your requirement). Your OP `Need to assign different levels of permissions to users from grid.` and your image has no relation whatsoever and it is quite confusing as to what you want. It is not easy to answer this without knowing the whole thing.

Comment: Take for example, i want to assign permission to John, i can make john as author, or restrict him or allow to do specific things alone so this is what i meant different levels of permissions as shown in drop down (2nd row) but i don't want to use inline edit like bringing in dropdown inside grid!

Comment: What is the restriction on not allowing in-line editing? Without knowing that, it is very difficult to know what would work. For example, you could group users by permissions in separate drag and drop lists. But that may hjave the same technical limitation. How many users will be in the 'grid'?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the WordPress admin for user permissions? Perhaps the 'Quick Edit' option that is used when editing Pages / Posts might be useful

Comment: Could you say why the possible method with the dropdown after clicking "Add" is not allowed. For example, your boss doesn't want you to use it? You can't get the program you are using to do it? Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

On clicking a row's Edit button you could pop up a dialog that contains a form allowing users to update the fields of that row.